# How is a rocket modeled?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

I hear that rockets are "not pushing back on anything" but I couldn't find any clear explanation of what they push and what push back occurs.

They expel matter but then the limit of what's "the rocket" and "the expelled matter" is rarely (never?) defined clearly. Many explanations seem to imply that the boundary is obvious and unambiguous, and should be an horizontal plane corresponding to the end of the nozzle. Which leads to a problem: if the boundary is unimportant, I can take another plane higher and cut the bottom of the rocket, and it would make zero difference.

How are rockets rigorously modeled in term of forces and action-reaction?

You can simply represent the center of mass of the complete rocket with its expelled gazes, and it's simple in a vacuum but in the atmosphere it isn't a closed system, and even less near the ground, *as it pushes on the launch pad*.

Comment: "Many explanations seem to imply that the boundary is obvious and unambiguous". Yes. That's because it is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Comment: @EmilioPisanty What is that unambiguous boundary then?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Where is the boundary defined?

Comment: Rockets *are so* pushing back on something: they push on their exhaust. That's what makes it move backward (and the rocket forward). And that tells you why and how to draw the line.

Comment: you assume the rocket with the gas is an isolated system so total momentum of the expelled gas plus rocket is conserved

Comment: you dont need to define a boundary

Comment: @Wolphramjonny "_you assume the rocket_" And that POV is fine w/ me. It feels good. The usual explanation has rockets "not pushing back on anything" and "action reaction" principle which is awfully unclear and needs a boundary between A and B.

Comment: dmakeee comment is correct, the gas and rocket push on each other, but it is easier to analyze the system with conservation of momentum, so the rocket is all the mass that is not a moving gas

Comment: @Wolphramjonny It's easier when in outer space; on the launch pad? You would have to model the push back on the Earth. Then it isn't a simple.

Comment: With a properly designed venturi nozzel there is very little effect from the external environment (up to a point, of course). The exhaust splashing on the launch pad doesn't really affect the rocket. The "pushing" happens in the combustion chamber which is isolated from the external pressure environment by a super-sonic choke (the location of the pressue wave is where to draw the line, BTW).

Comment: @dmckee If the rocket is too low, at some point it must have an effect.

Comment: Super-sonic flows have properties that are not obvious from day-to-day experience, so common sense is of marginal value here unless it is bolstered by an understanding of how these systems work. Certainly it is possible to defeat the venturi effect, but you need to keep in mind that these devices were designed to run in their environments. People made them so that they would work.

Comment: Re, "pushing on the launch pad." Launch pads for space vehicles usually have holes directly under the rocket nozzles for the specific purpose of _preventing_ any "push" between the rocket and the pad. If the holes weren't there, the extra "push" (gas pressure and sound waves) between the launch vehicle and the pad would be destructive, not just to the "pad" structure, but also to the launch vehicle.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The flow must stop somewhere, unless you are digging a hole through Earth. Is there a critical distance where it can push back?

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions have been furnished in the long list of comments others have provided here. I will try to summarize them with a minimum of rocket science.

To start with, *reaction motors* have been rigorously modeled for over a hundred years. Their behavior is so well-understood that the design of reaction motors is an *engineering discipline*; as such, an adequate understanding of the topic will be found in any engineering text that deals with aerospace propulsion. But here are the bare-bones basics:

Imagine yourself sitting on a skateboard with a bowling ball in your lap, and a wall facing you. You take the bowling ball in your hands and as forcefully as you can manage, you throw it straight at the wall like a shot put.

You are pushing on the ball, which means *the ball is pushing on you*. In response to the ball *pushing on you*, you and the skateboard you are sitting on scoot away from the wall, and an instant later the ball strikes the wall.

Whether or not the ball hits the wall is irrelevant; you and the skateboard have already been propelled away from the wall before the ball hits it because you were pushing on the ball *and the ball was pushing on you*.

A rocket motor *pushes on its exhaust* and the exhaust *pushes back on the motor*; this reaction force is the *thrust* generated by the motor and it is generated whether or not there happens to be a launch pad in the path of the exhaust.

All else follows from that principle, and the details of this process you seek will be found in the texts I mentioned above. The experts here may be able to steer you to a specific book on this.

Comment: If the exhaust pushes back on the rocket, shouldn't also push back on the air, on the soil, on the rest of the exhaust?

Comment: it pushes on those things, but there is no way for any of those things to *push back on the rocket engine* once the exhaust has left the nozzle.

Comment: Then you should remove the dead weight that is the nozzle, as nothing can push back on it, once it has left

Comment: read a book about nozzles.

Comment: That doesn't refute my argument.

Comment: the book will.....